# Projected coordinate reference system for aviation navigation and instrument approach charts

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to find out if aviation organizations like the ICAO have written guides for what projection CRS must be used in the following charts:

1. High/low altitude navigation charts
2. IFR approach procedures charts

I am using QGIS.

Comment: https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2014/ECARAIM/REF06-Doc9881.pdf contains some information on charting https://www.casa.gov.au/sites/g/files/net351/f/_assets/main/lib91135/an04_cons.pdf is also a good source of information. The WAC (world aeronautical charts) that I have dealt with were in Lambert’s Conformal Conic Projection https://vfrg.casa.gov.au/pre-flight-planning/preparation/charts/. It is also important to note that distances are in metres but elevations are in feet as altimeters read in feet - otherwise instrument approaches may result in sudden stopping at 1/3 the height.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i will read those documents

Comment: Hi, i searched for the documents but i did not find an answer. they only say it has to be wgs84 but they do not specify which one. in Qgis there are many CRS types named WGS84. which EPSG number should be used?

Comment: WGS84 is a Datum and Projection, the differentiation can be confusing. Charting is historically done using a projection to flatten out the Earths surface onto a sheet of paper (or PDF/web form etc..). The docs state that the datum should be WGS84 but leave the user to apply whatever projection suits the map, a small sheet for a city wide area could be UTM, Lamberts  or Albers for a state and perhaps even Mercator for a continent. Be sure to state implicitly which projection of WGS84 you are using so the educated user can use the chart within the limitations of the projection.

Comment: Some very serious mistakes can occur if the chart is *assumed to be WGS84* as the specification states and the datum is not WGS84 - people have died because of this! One horrible example occurred fairly recently where coordinates for an air strike were given to a pilot, assumed to be WGS84 same as their onboard navigation, but were in fact in a local datum which was ~300m different hence the air strike was tragically and fatally in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me, so if i understand Correctly the projection is up to the map maker but the CRS should be WGS84 based. if i may ask a second question, are there any icao/faa/easa set standards for which map projections to use for the different aviation charts? for example the IFR aproach plates? High/low altitude charts ?

Comment: That seems to be the case, the projection is flexible but must be based on the WGS84 datum. As to the specifications you mention I can't say, the aviation maps I've worked on were WAC (World Aeronautical Chars) in Lamberts CC and JOGA (Joint Operations Graphic : Air) in UTM but that was more than 10 years ago. One of the deliverable requirements was a CADRG like one of the choices https://www.dla.mil/Aviation/Offers/Products/Mapping/Digital.aspx and explained https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_file_formats (note the link to MIL-STD-2411 which might be a worthy reference) which were WGS84/Geo.